# How to enable video forwarding?

Tags: php, html, video

I am having this simple code for playing a video in HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous" />

    <!-- local css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./index.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <!-- display video -->
    <video src="./vid_store/Phum Viphurit - Pluto [Live Session].mp4"
        width="400px"
        controls></video>
</body>
```

While the `controls` attribute enables navigation for the video, it doesn't work when the code is parsed using the PHP server with the command `php -S localhost:3000`. It just returns back to the start of the video when I want to move to any point of the timeline.

How can I enable that `controls` feature?

Comment: It may depend on the format of the video. Either way, it's nothing to do with PHP, this is entirely about what's happening in your browser and how it interacts with the video file.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you mean. Are you asking for a scrubber bar? If it worked before you moved it to a PHP file, then it should work now as well, unless you've made some other changes that would cause issues. The fact that the file is a PHP file doesn't change how HTML works or how the browser renders the HTML.

Comment: I think I have expressed my question in the wrong way. What I mean is: given the code above in an HTML file (e.g., `index.html` ); While the `control` attribute enables video navigation, it doesn't work when the code is parsed using PHP server with command `php -S localhost:3000`. So I am looking for a way to enable that attribute

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.
 The same is true for `<link>`

Comment: You should [edit] your question then, to clarify this point

Comment: Proper "seeking" in an online video requires that the browser is able to request specific _parts_ of the video resource. The server that delivers the video content, needs to support _HTTP Range Requests_ for this. And the tiny built-in server PHP itself provides, likely doesn't.

Comment: Based on what CBroe says, I'd suggest using a proper webserver such as Apache or IIS for your testing in this case.

Comment: Hm i guess i would look for another webserver then. Thanks everyone for the help!

Comment: @JohnPham See if you can install a local server (_eg:_ **XAMPP** server) and test your html/php on that locally installed server. This recreates from your hard drive the effect of going to an HTTP server (but it's just a folder on your disk).

Comment: @VC.One ...and a service running on the machine. It doesn't "recreate the effect of going to a HTTP server", it **is** a HTTP server. It just runs on the local machine, instead of on a public one, that's all. There's no emulation or anything like that. There's no practical difference in terms of implementation. Apache is Apache, wherever you run it.

Comment: @ADyson Don't forget to mention it's a complete package (including a DataBase etc) , comes with a visual user interface, and easy to install in few clicks. I've been using Xampp for a decade now, but I think the Asker's level might need all this to be explained. If they are told to just install Aache, they might struggle (or find tedious) with manually setting up things via terminal command. Installing Xampp means in a few clicks they can test their code in the same hour of their download/install time...

Comment: @VC.One well yes, but OP only needs the HTTP server bit for this particular issue. They could just install Apache alone, in theory. I agree XAMPP would likely make it simpler to set up (and also give them other tools to use, too). But I didn't take issue with that, the problem with your comment was the wording implying it was just some sort of disk-based emulation of HTTP (whatever that would actually mean in practice), rather than actually the real thing :-)

Comment: @ADyson **(1)** Okay I hear you properly now. Basically you're saying Xampp would be too bloated (or is too much) for this specific code testing? Installing raw Apache is faster to start on the testing then upgrade to extras like Xampp later on? Personally I think if their first move is to install Xampp, then it will just solve a lot of future problems/expectations at once. **(2)** The real problem of video seek not working is that some browsers (Chrome) do not like "streamed" video tag sources (_ie:_ it expects an MP4 filename, not a PHP script that returns bytes else it won't allow seeking).

Comment: @ADyson Oh now your comment has auto updated...? I answered the old version.

Comment: @VC.One I edited it pretty soon after posting (you only get 5 minutes, as you probably know). But yeah sometimes SO doesn't show the edits to others unless they do something on the page, it's a bit annoying.

Comment: @VC.One `The real problem of video seek not working is that some browsers (Chrome) do not like "streamed" video tag sources (ie: it expects an MP4 filename, not a PHP script that returns bytes else it won't allow seeking)`...true, but looking at the OP's code, that doesn't seem to be an issue in this case, they are referencing an mp4 file.

Comment: @ADyson Back from a break. I'm always learning new tips/tricks from the questions of others, so I hope you don't mind the _"extended discussion"_? Regarding _"They are referencing an mp4 file"_, yes under normal circumstance's it should work fine, but they re involving PHP here. I wonder if the effect of `php -S ...` results in the URLs being accessed in a way that has a same effect as doing a PHP `readFile` or `passThru` command. A clue of such PHP behaviour is in the seek bar not responding. I suppose it depends if PHP itself is in charge of getting the URL requests for sources in the HTML.

Comment: @VC.One it might also depend on what CBroe's earlier comment said about support for HTTP range requests...that would be the case of the webserver supporting such a thing, regardless of whether it passes such requests through a PHP script or not.